# When building libicu on ubuntu, where do I define U_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE?

Tags: ubuntu, icu

I am building libicu on Ubuntu Linux.

In [Recommended Build Options](http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/tags/release-55-1/readme.html#HowToBuild), the documentation suggests that I should use `-DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=0` and `-DU_CHARSET_IS_UTF8=1`.

My build process is as follows.

```
wget -nv http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/55.1/icu4c-55_1-src.tgz -O icu4c-55_1-src.tgz
tar -zxvf icu4c-55_1-src.tgz 
mkdir -p build
cd build
../icu/source/runConfigureICU Linux
make check
```

**Where do I provide the arguments `-DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=0` and `-DU_CHARSET_IS_UTF8=1`?** Neither `configure` nor `make` seem to accept these arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For command line try using: CPPFLAGS="-DU_CHARSET_IS_UTF8=1" see [here](http://site.icu-project.org/repository/tips/linux)

So your command-line becomes

```
wget -nv http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/55.1/icu4c-55_1-src.tgz -O icu4c-55_1-src.tgz
tar -zxvf icu4c-55_1-src.tgz 
mkdir -p build
cd build
CPPFLAGS="-DU_CHARSET_IS_UTF8=1" ../icu/source/runConfigureICU Linux
make check
```

Or you can modify the headers directly. see [here](http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/trunk/readme.html#RecBuild)
Good if you're rebuilding a lot and want a simple command line but does require you to re-apply the change should the source file get updated.

Comment: Oh, I see, so my command line would become `CPPFLAGS="-DU_CHARSET_IS_UTF8=1" ../icu/source/runConfigureICU Linux`

Comment: As per Scott's answer, the arguments need to go in the environment variable CPPFLAGS, so that they will end up getting passed to the C++ compiler.